# DataTables warning: table id={id} - Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, datatables

I know above error is explain here " [LINK](http://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1) "

All is working fine in my `local-host` thats  no error popup , nothing in my local-host.

But on my online server i am getting above link error : i am not getting what and where is wrong as when i refresh my page after error  then i get data properly .

It works for some time and then again start giving me error and again after refresh of page , error is not seen and my table list all data properly .

I check my all MySQL query on my server its working properly and fine.

```
   var oTableL1 = $('#table1').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true, 
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "includes/db/list_db.php", 
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "tablequeryone" } ); 

           // aoData : passing parameter in my list_db.php where
                       i have used if else-if  code for resp. which is working fine
                       in my local-host, also on server after refresh

        }
    }); 

      var oTableL2 = $('#table2').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true, 
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "includes/db/list_db.php", 
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "tablequerytwo" } );
        }
    }); 

      var oTableL3 = $('#table3').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true, 
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "includes/db/list_db.php", 
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "tablequerythree } );
        }
    });
```

**ONLINE SERVER :** IF I REFRESH MY PAGE then some time it get my data properly but some time its show me error , but after refresh of page it show me data properly without any error .. not getting what wrong.

same thing is happening for search and pagination and records list .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting output on random refresh it has to do with the data table initialization and assignment of data. There are multiple scenarios that can lead to above error;

- If data is being assigned to grid prior to element is registered in DOM
- Data table is being initialized multiple times when its already available in the DOM

  - Solution; Clear the table and reassign the data.
- Data mist match (in short grid contains columns; Col1, Col2, Col3 while table array is 
        not of same length)

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply, i have check my columns properly) its all fine, also as said its working all fine in my local-host , only creating issue with my ONLINE SERVER and that to after refresh data is seen ..is this issue to server side ?.. also can u tell me "clear the table and reassign the data" how i can achieve this ? ..and last i have many record in my table an it take long time to show it continuously show processing for some min ..

Comment: To clear table you can use the api fnSettings. Please check API doc. oTable.fnSettings().aoRowCallback =[];  oTable.fnSettings().aoDrawCallback= [];